# Regex if valid WebSocket address

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex for valid websocket address but I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Here's what I've already tried

```
/(^ws:\/\/|^wss:\/\/)(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:)|([a-zA-Z]+))([0-9]{1,5})/gm
```

Regex should match below

```
ws://0.0.0.0:8080
wss://192.168.0.25:12345
ws://localhost:3333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(wss?:\/\/)([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-zA-Z]+):([0-9]{1,5})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zf51bZ/2)

Note that `[a-zA-Z]+` won't be enough as it only matches ASCII letters.

Use `[^\/]+` instead if you want to match any chars but `/`:

```
/^(wss?:\/\/)([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[^\/]+):([0-9]{1,5})$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zf51bZ/3).

To just match FQDNs, use

```
/^(wss?:\/\/)([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|(?=[^\/]{1,254}:[0-9]{1,5}$)(?:(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(?:xn--+)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}):([0-9]{1,5})$/
```

Adaped from this solution by [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012067/3832970). There are all the explanations in his post. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zf51bZ/5).

The main problem was with `:`: it was only matched after numeric IP pattern, not after the `[a-zA-Z]+`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(wss?:\/\/)` - `ws://` or `wss://`
- `([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-zA-Z]+)` - 1 to 3 digits followed with 3 occurrences of `.` and 1 to 3 digits or 1+ letters (or, if `[^\/]+` is used, 1+ chars other than `/`)
- `:` - `:`
- `([0-9]{1,5})` - 1 to 5 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Also, see a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(wss%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F)(%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D)%7B3%7D%7C%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)%3A(%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C5%7D)%24).

Comment: This does not work for FQDN. You need to expand your [a-zA-Z]+ part to match any domain name.

Comment: @JánStibila That is not the question here, but  `[a-zA-Z]` can be replaced with `[^/]` here to match any char but `/`.

Comment: Well question asks for "regex for valid websocket address". ws://example.com:5555 is a valid address. [^/] wont work, because there are invalid characters that can't be used in domain name (whitespace characters for exampe).

Comment: @JánStibila Ok, adapted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012067/3832970) for the current one.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would rather do just 1 group for the whole match; eg: (wss?:\/\/[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[^\/]+:[0-9]{1,5})...

Answer (score 1):

The second alternation does not match the `:`

You could move it outside of the alternation to match it for both of the options.

If you don't need the capturing groups, you could omit them.

The first alternation could be shortened making the extra s optional:

```
^(wss?:\/\/)(([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]+)):[0-9]{1,5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TIv91F/1)